# How to fix: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL ports

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I am trying to connect my visual studio program to MySql. I keep getting errors for the connection. I am running MySql 8.0 on my machine.

```
string strConnection = "server=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0; database=dtcdental; uid=root; pwd=mmypwd";

    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(strConnection);
    return connection;
```

I get the error unable to connect to specified MySql hosts with this code.

```
string strConnection = "server=localhost; port=3306; database=dtcdental; uid=root; pwd=mypwd";

    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(strConnection);
    return connection;
```

I get the error client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client with this code.

I have opened ports on the windows firewall and I believe I have allowed access through McAfee Livesafe as well.

Comment: This error cannot occur unless you *are* connecting to the port.  You are connecting and failing to authenticate.

Comment: So I have the connection in my server explorer and when I test the connection there, it says it succeeds. I am using the same log in info in server explorer. Also are you referring to the first or second error I am receiving?

Comment: I didn't initially see the first error.  You appear to have paraphrased it or omitted some of the words.  I was referring to the second.

Comment: So I just looked deeper into the server explorer and found this for the connection string: @"server=localhost;user id=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=dtcdental;port=3306;password=password@"; and if I do it like this I get the error access denired for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password:YES).

Comment: If I do @"server=localhost;user id=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=dtcdental;port=3306;password=password"; without the @ I get the error, the given key was not present in the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you execute 'telnet localhost 3306' on the commandline on your machine?

From the MySQL documentation:
*If there is a MySQL server running and listening to the port, you should get a response that includes the server's version number. If you get an error such as telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused, then there is no server running on the given port.*

And do you have installed the latest version of the .NET MySQL connector? That should fix it.
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

*Connector/NET is a fully-managed ADO.NET driver for MySQL.*

*MySQL Connector/NET 8.0 is compatible with all MySQL versions starting with MySQL 5.5. Additionally, MySQL Connector/NET 8.0 supports the new X DevAPI for development with MySQL Server 8.0.*

Comment: I have the latest version of the connector downloaded. When I try to execute 'telnet localhost 3306' in command prompt I get: 'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Installing Telnet client in Windows is easy: 
Hold down the Windows Key, then press “R“.
The Run dialog box appears. Type: pkgmgr /iu:”TelnetClient”

Comment: now I get this:  8.0.16,1W,Z ^="5K`(
                           caching_sha2_password!#08S01Got packets out of order

Connection to host lost.